# Login page redirection based on user role using javascript and firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

What I'm trying to accomplish is to create a user login using html/javascript with firestore as my backend provider. Currently my code returns an error

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of
> undefined
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of undefined

I understand that get() takes time to run so I used the function then() as a promise when get() works. At the moment the only thing that works is the

```
 const userCredential = await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(data.email, data.password);
```

because the console log shows `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged()` but no redirection to any page based on user (based on its occupation) is happening because the `uid` cannot be found.

here is my .js code

```
(function(){//initialize the firebase app
    var config = {

        }; 

        firebase.initializeApp(config);
        var auth = null;
        var loginBtn= document.getElementById('btnLogin');
        // var user = db.collection("users");
        // var db = firebase.firestore();
        firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION;

    //Login
    loginBtn.addEventListener('click', async e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if( $('#email').val() != '' && $('#password').val() != '' ){
        //login the user
        var data = {
            email: $('#email').val(),
            password: $('#password').val()
        };

    try{
        const userCredential = await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(data.email, data.password);
        let uid = userCredential.user.uid;
        var documents = await firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(uid);
        documents.get().then(function(doc){
            if(doc.data['occupation'] != 'Doctor'){
                window.location.href = "patientDashboard.php"; 
            }
            else {
                window.location.href = "doctorDashboard.php";  
            }
        });
    } 
        catch(err) {
            console.log("Login Failed!", err);
            window.alert("Login Failed!", err);
        }
    }
});
})();
```

I hope I explained it well, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer to my redirection problem, it resides in fixing the query code within the `try{}` code.

```
try{
    const userCredential = await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(data.email, data.password);
    let uid = userCredential.user.uid;
    var document = await firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(uid).get();
    //document is a DocumentSnapshot, we can call the get() method
    if (document.get('occupation') != 'Doctor'){
       window.location.href = "patientDashboard.php"; 
    }
    else {
       window.location.href = "doctorDashboard.php";  
    }                   
}    
catch(err){
    console.log("Login Failed!", err);
    window.alert("Login Failed!", err);
}
```

**DISCLAIMER**

Be aware that with this code you are NOT implementing a genuine role-based access control system. This is code simply for an academic requirement that I am currently developing and in no way being used for deployment to any clients. You are just redirecting the `user` based on a value in its user document. Someone could easily reverse engineer your app and redirects to the wrong page.

Full credit to Renaud Tarnec for fixing the error!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this line

`firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(data.email, data.password); //this will work`

actually works, because, as the docs [say here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth.html#sign-inwith-email-and-password), that method is asynchronous, so it returns a promise. You would have to use something like this:

```
const userCredential = await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(data.email, data.password);
let uid = userCredential.user.uid;
// do stuff
```

So we're awaiting the result of the signIn function and then we're using the value it returned.

Also, as we're using `await`, the lambda function assigned as an event listener should be declared `async` .

```
//Login
loginBtn.addEventListener('click', async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        ...
```

Comment: Note that you could also use the `then()` method as follows: `firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(data.email, data.password).then(userCredential => {let uid = userCredential.user.uid;})`

Comment: @victor vlad I edited my code (see original question) based on your answer but the aforementioned errors are still present when I inspect my work through chrome browser